# Regular Expression for greater than date format xx-xx-xxxx

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have a single text file with 40,000 records. I need to locate all items greater than October 1st 2011. The format is 01-10-2011 - How can I do this using regular expression?

Comment: Not sure regex is the best way to go here. What OS or language are you using?

Comment: What language are you doing this in? And why do you want to use a regular expression?

Comment: Regexps are very much the wrong tool for this, as they use the _representation_ of the dates and not the _value_ of them.

Comment: I want to do this using regular expression via Dreamweaver or Notepad++ in Windows.

Comment: You need to indicate the regular expression and/or programming environment you are using. Regular expressions are not a suitable facility for comparing dates, but we have no way to know which direction to point you unless you specify how you're parsing and handling the records.

Answer (score 3):

It probably shouldn't be done, but it can be done:

```
([0-3][2-9]|[1-3]1)-10-2011|[0-3][0-9]-1[12]-2011|[0-3][0-9]-[01][0-9]-201[2-9]
```

This assumes all dates are DD-MM-YYYY and valid, and that you don't need to find dates further in the future than 2019, for which it could be adapted if necessary.

Tested in Dreamweaver CS5, and I doubt they've changed their regex engine much over time.  Notepad++ regex doesn't support the bar, which turned out to be rather crippling.

For a breakdown of why this works, we have 3 top level alternatives for matching, separated by the bar (`|`). The first alternative is:

```
 ([0-3][2-9]|[1-3][0-9])-10-2011
```

Which matches any dates in October 2011 with DD not equal to 01. In order to support 02-31 at the character level, a sub bar group, `([0-3][2-9]|[1-3]1)` is necessary. The left hand side of this bar matches 02-39, omitting 11, 21, and 31, and the right hand side accepts precisely those omissions.

The next top level alternative is:

```
[0-3][0-9]-1[12]-2011
```

Which matches any day in the months of November and December of 2011.

And the final group is:

```
[0-3][0-9]-[01][0-9]-201[2-9]
```

Which matches any day of any month in 2012-2019.

Comment: ([0-9]{2}-[1][0-2]-2011|[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-201[2-9])

Comment: This is what I got collaborated with an internal person. Thank you all! All dates are in a valid format, but the raw data file can not be worked with in any other way. I know its a challenge with out seeing what I have. But thank you!

Comment: We were posting at the same time! Thank you!!

Comment: @user1206919 Ah no probs. Your regex does accept 01-10-2011 though - making it not accept October 1st was the hardest part! Glad the problem is sorted anyway.