# Regex to match date string greater than certain date

Tags: regex, apache-spark

I have a requirement to fetch date (yyyyMMdd format) directories greater than certain date .
For example, need to fetch all dates starting from 20190605 .

I have directories like below.

> /tmp/20190607 /tmp/20190606 /tmp/20190605 /tmp/20190604

Need a regexp pattern to fetch directories greater than 20190605 .

TIA

Comment: To my knowledge Regex is mostly used to match specific character patterns I don't think it's intended to filter date with it. There might still be a way to do it see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318402/regular-expression-for-greater-than-date-format-xx-xx-xxxx

Comment: I need a regex to match date string greater than 20190605 .

Comment: I know what I tried to say was that regex might not be the best way to go about this. If you have a list of directories like above maybe split them into a collection, fetch the dates with a regex and process the dates as date objects to filter them. You are free to try it with regex tough I left you a link which could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is not so many dates after `20190605`, maybe this simple expression would work:

```
\/tmp\/(2019060[6-9]|201906[1-3][0-9]|20190[7-9][0-9]{2})
```

which is simple to modify, if a date is missing.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GgbMus/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: There will be a new directory created every day .